# Fine tuning Routes in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, routes

I have the following routes defined:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "EventInfo", // Route name
    "Events/{year}/{month}/{day}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Events", action = "Index", year = UrlParameter.Optional, month = UrlParameter.Optional, day = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "EventType", // Route name
    "Events/Type/{id}/{year}/{month}/{day}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Events", action = "Type", id = UrlParameter.Optional, year = UrlParameter.Optional, month = UrlParameter.Optional, day = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```

I am seeing some "weird" behavior when navigating.  For instance I have an Html.ActionLink on my main menu which is defined like:

```
<li class="@item.Class">@Html.ActionLink(item.Title, item.Action, item.Controller, null, new { @class="standard" } )</li>
```

I also have a sidebar secondary menu defined the same way in my View - I just change what Model feeds the 2 different (Partial) Views.  For instance, my Main Menu's Model looks like:

```
public MenuItems()
{
    List = new List<Menu> {
                    new Menu { Controller="Home", Action="Index", Title="Home", Class="grid-2 menubutton" },
                    new Menu { Controller="Info", Action="Index", Title="Information", Class="grid-2 menubutton" },
                    new Menu { Controller="Events", Action="Index", Title="Events", Class="grid-2 menubutton" },
                    new Menu { Controller="Guilds", Action="Index", Title="Guilds", Class="grid-2 menubutton" },
                    new Menu { Controller="Populace", Action="Index", Title="Caer Galenites", Class="grid-3 menubutton" },
                    new Menu { Controller="Loop", Action="Index", Title="Get in the Loop", Class="grid-3 menubutton" }
                };
}
```

Now, I am at the point of testing my Events page (see the Routes above) so I am altering the URL once I am on the main Events page.  i.e.:  I click on Events in the main menu and get to http://site.com/Events and I see my event listings.  I then append a year like http://site.com/Events/2011 and the filter works.  Append a Month like http://site.com/Events/2011/9 and now I see the current months' events.  So far, so good.

I then hover over one of the sidebar menu items expecting to see http://site.com/Events/Type/Kingdom but instead I am seeing http://site.com/Events/Type/Kingdom/2011/9.  I hover over my main menu link and instead of http://site.com/Events I see http://site.com/Events/2011/9.  If I hover over the other Main Menu items they are showing the correct URLs.

Why?  How do I "fix it"?

TIA

Comment: You seem to be making all your url tokens optional. Only the last token should be optional. If I had one advice to give you when defining your routes: if a parameter is optional and this parameter is not the **last** parameter in your route definition, then this parameter should be part of the query string and not part of the path i.e. this parameter should not even appear in your routes. If you don't follow this simple advice you are heading towards a nightmare.

Comment: Yes.  I can do it that way.  The site owner requested friendly URLs without QueryStrings.  Don't know if it will be doable or not.

Comment: Chaging the Date part to yyyy-mm-dd so it comes in as a single string now.  Had to write a fairly extensive date checker to pull all the parts apart but that works well now too.  Will play with it a few days and see how it goes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the advice in the comments above I got it all working.  Instead of having the date parts as part of the URL (yyy/mm/dd) I opted for a single date string (yyyy-mm-dd or yyyy-mm or yyyy) and have a parser to pull that apart then bring back the correct listings.